# Generate Testing Data with a PL/pgSQL Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function / procedure, that allow me to generate data in a certain table for testing purposes. Also that function would simply perform a certain number of insert of 'fake' data.

I think im making mistakes around the dynamic query(the insert part of the procedure), missing understanting how to properly use string quotes.

Actually the function look like this:

```
DECLARE
  i_counter INTEGER;
  insertQuery TEXT;

BEGIN
  i_counter := startcount;

  WHILE i_counter < qtainsert LOOP
    insertQuery := 'INSERT INTO '
                   || tablename 
                   || '(message_id, from_uid, to_uid, oggetto, content, datetime)' 
                   || 'VALUES(DEFAULT, 0, 0,'''
                   || baseobj || i_counter || ''',''' 
                   || basemsg || i_counter 
                   || ''', NOW() )';

    i_counter := i_counter + 1;

    EXECUTE insertQuery;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

i call the function in this way:

```
SELECT insert_data('messaggio', 1, 10, 'oggetto', 'messggio');
```

but i get this error:
[image]

I think the problem is related to the string quotes, but the error output is strange, it looks like it try to execute a SELECT instead of execute the function with the synamic INSERTS inside

thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: Could you replace the line "i_counter := i_counter  + 1" with "RAISE EXCEPTION '%', insertQuery" and post the output  ?

Comment: Can you please add the actual query as (formatted) text?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : i wanted to post the whole function in text format, but that tool im using(phppgadmin) look to don't permit to do it XD

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt : for sure i ll do it now and post the output

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt : the output is the same also trying to catch the exception, i still beleave is a problem of parameters passage in the form of string

Comment: Please improve your copy/paste foo and replace the images!

Comment: We *very much* prefer code as text over images.

Comment: yea i got that, but phppgadmin look to don't have a way to see the whole function, because it surround parameters part whit damn forms.... but if you prefer trunked code instead of complete picture of the situation that's okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bad usage of double quotes.

It should be

```
insert_query := 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename ...
```

You should not replace double quotes and single quotes.

Comment: thank you for the answer, something changed, i get an other error output: SQL error:

ERROR:  column "oggetto1" does not exist
LINE 1: ... to_uid, oggetto, content, datetime) VALUES(0, 0, oggetto1,m...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO messaggio(from_uid, to_uid, oggetto, content, datetime) VALUES(0, 0, oggetto1,messaggio1, NOW )
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "insert_data" line 13 at EXECUTE statement
In statement:
SELECT insert_data('messaggio', 1, 10, 'oggetto', 'messaggio');

Comment: maybee i can succeed to fix it now, i'll let you know